# Standard $n$-simplex visualization

Tags: simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the standard simplicial $n$-simplex $\Delta[n]$ is the simplicial set which is represented (as a presheaf) by the object $[n]$ in the simplex category, so $\Delta[n]= \Delta(-,[n])$.

Very often it is said that standard $n$-simplex can be pictured like this (for small $n$):
[image]

But I don't understand it. It doesn't look like a realization functor from simplicial sets to topological spaces. And standard $n$-simplex as a simplicial set has $\omega$ many non-empty sets of $k$-simplices, not finitely many.

The same goes for pictures of $k^{th}$ horns:
[image]

So my question is why $n$-simplex or horn can be depicted in such way?

Comment: Such pictures typically only depict _nondegenerate_ simplices, of which there are only finitely many for an $n$-simplex.  This is what is depicted in your diagrams.  For a full picture of a simplicial set, including degenerate simplices, see Figure 12 in https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4221.

Comment: Geometric realisation doesn’t depend on the degenerate simplices; so you could say, they are present but invisible in the picture since they contribute nothing to the space